typescript how to strictly and generically typing return object based on input type
I'm trying to write a generic function that

takes a collection of things,
takes an object

where the keys match the collection of things

where the values are functions that return Promises of differing types,



and returns an object with the same keys but with the values typed to the matching resolved types.

So far I've come up with the following, but I'm at a loss as to how to type the return type correctly.

// ---- Example Usage ---- 
type DataItem = { id1: string; id2: number; data: unknown };
type Type1 = { type1: string };
type Type2 = { type2: string };

const collection: DataItem[] = [
    { id1: 'asdfasdf', id2: 123123, data: 'blah' },
    { id1: 'zxcvzxcv', id2: 345675647, data: 'zing zang' },
];

loadReferencedRecords(collection, {
    id1: () => Promise.resolve({ type1: 'asdfas' } as Type1),
    id2: () => Promise.resolve({ type2: 'asdfas' } as Type2),
}).then(({
    id1: type1sById, // <<<  Wanting Type1, not both
    id2: type2sById, // <<<  Wanting Type2, not both
}) => {
    const type1 = type1sById['asdfasdf']; //  Wanting "Type1" but getting "Type 1 | Type 2"
});


// ---- Implementation ---- 

export async function loadReferencedRecords<
    Item extends { [key: string ]: unknown },
    Getters extends Partial<{ [key in keyof Item]: (id: string) => Promise<unknown> }>,
    Key extends keyof Getters,
>(
    items: Item[],
    getters: Getters
): Promise<{
    [key in Key]: Record<
        string,
        Exclude<Awaited<ReturnType<Exclude<
            Getters[Key], // <<<< ???? 
        undefined>>>,undefined>
    >
}> {
    return {}; // 
}


You need to use key (literal type of each key) instead of Key (the union type of the keys):
// ---- Example Usage ---- 
type DataItem = { id1: string; id2: number; data: unknown };
type Type1 = { type1: string };
type Type2 = { type2: string };

const collection: DataItem[] = [
    { id1: 'asdfasdf', id2: 123123, data: 'blah' },
    { id1: 'zxcvzxcv', id2: 345675647, data: 'zing zang' },
];

loadReferencedRecords(collection, {
    id1: () => Promise.resolve({ type1: 'asdfas' } as Type1),
    id2: () => Promise.resolve({ type2: 'asdfas' } as Type2),
}).then(({
    id1: type1sById, // <<<  inferred: Type1
    id2: type2sById, // <<<  inferred: Type2
}) => {
    const type1 = type1sById['asdfasdf']; //  inferred: Type 1
});


// ---- Implementation ---- 

export async function loadReferencedRecords<
    Item extends { [key: string ]: unknown },
    Getters extends Partial<{ [key in keyof Item]: (id: string) => Promise<unknown> }>,
    Key extends keyof Getters,
>(
    items: Item[],
    getters: Getters
): Promise<{
    [key in Key]: Record<
        string,
        Exclude<Awaited<ReturnType<Exclude<
            Getters[key], // << not Key
        undefined>>>,undefined>
    >
}> {
    return {}; // 
}


You can use key?!  Why am I only finding about this now?  You, sir, are a genius.
